# Почему не работает пакет pymorphy2 на Python 3.11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymorphy2, python-3.11

Установил модуль pymorphy2 в виртуальное окружение, импортировал и вызвал класс из этого модуля, после этого интерпретатор вернул мне ошибку. Всё работало хорошо пока не обновил Python до 3.11

---

#### Мой код

```py
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
```

---

#### Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\.admin\.Files\.Python\.AiogramBot\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "S:\.admin\.Files\.Python\.AiogramBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 224, in __init__
    self._init_units(units)
  File "S:\.admin\.Files\.Python\.AiogramBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 235, in _init_units
    self._units.append((self._bound_unit(unit), False))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "S:\.admin\.Files\.Python\.AiogramBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 246, in _bound_unit
    unit = unit.clone()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "S:\.admin\.Files\.Python\.AiogramBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\units\base.py", line 35, in clone
    return self.__class__(**self._get_params())
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "S:\.admin\.Files\.Python\.AiogramBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\units\base.py", line 76, in _get_params
    (key, getattr(self, key, None)) for key in self._get_param_names()
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "S:\.admin\.Files\.Python\.AiogramBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\units\base.py", line 70, in _get_param_names
    args, varargs, kw, default = inspect.getargspec(cls.__init__)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'. Did you mean: 'getargs'?
```

Comment: пробовали ли зайти на гитхаб данной библиотеки? может какие-то там есть изменения? может наткнулись бы на данный [issue](https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2/issues/159)

Comment: На гитхаб заходить пробовал, библиотека не обновлялась 2 года, я работал с ней очень много и понимаю что делаю, сам класс MorphAnalyzer в ней есть

Comment: не хочу гадать, я но я бы поостерегся вообще пользоваться питоном 3.11

Comment: Ну да, пишут в 3.11 этот метод удалили. Хотите - разбирайтесь, чем его можно заменить. Но вкратце - просто нет совместимости с 3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Информация будет обновляться.**

Я когда-то немного контрибьютил в pymorphy2, слежу за ситуацией с ним.

Проект pymorphy2 в последнее время (годы) находится в замороженном состоянии (см. issue [Проект кажется заброшенным, обновление](https://github.com/pymorphy2/pymorphy2/issues/160)), крайний коммит в master - [от сентября 2020 года](https://github.com/pymorphy2/pymorphy2/commits/master), автор долгое время не отвечал на issues и pull-реквесты.

Поддержку Python 3.11 в него не добавлена, хотя [есть соответствующий pull-request](https://github.com/pymorphy2/pymorphy2/pull/161).

Сейчас можно:

- Временно откатиться на Python 3.10 (версии Python 3.11 на данный момент меньше года, некоторые другие библиотеки могли тоже не обновиться под эту версию)
- Или воспользоваться форком pymorphy2 - [pymorphy3](https://github.com/no-plagiarism/pymorphy3), поддержку Python 3.11 в него уже [влили](https://github.com/no-plagiarism/pymorphy3/pull/7).

  ```
  pip install pymorphy3
  ```

  Установка словарей, если они вдруг не установились вместе с pymorphy3 (словари от pymorphy2 не подойдут, там есть разница в формате самих словарей):

  ```
  pip install pymorphy3-dicts-ru
  ```
- Использовать "workaround" из комментариев к issue: https://github.com/pymorphy2/pymorphy2/issues/160#issuecomment-1486657176

  ```
  def pymorphy2_311_hotfix():
      from inspect import getfullargspec
      from pymorphy2.units.base import BaseAnalyzerUnit

      def _get_param_names_311(klass):
          if klass.__init__ is object.__init__:
              return []
          args = getfullargspec(klass.__init__).args
          return sorted(args[1:])

      setattr(BaseAnalyzerUnit, '_get_param_names', _get_param_names_311)


  def pymorphy2_example():
      pymorphy2_311_hotfix()
      morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
      parse_result = morph.parse('хочу')
      print(parse_result[0].normal_form)  # >>> хотеть
  ```

---

Недавно автор pymorphy2 все-таки [откликнулся](https://github.com/pymorphy2/pymorphy2/issues/160#issuecomment-1360976556), проект [перенесли в отдельную организацию](https://github.com/pymorphy2). Планируется, что он будет поддерживаться несколькими меинтейнерами (а не одним человеком, от которого все зависит, как было до этого).

Comment: Практически репортаж в прямом эфире получается

Comment: Так то этот форк pymorphy3 хорош? Ну то есть имеет смысл всегда использовать или есть подводные камни? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну, плюс в том, что в нем хотя бы какие-то подвижки есть, в оригинале за 2 года тишина. А так они взаимозаменяемы (кроме формата словарей, там какое-то поле расширили, как я понял).

Answer (score 1):

Можно внести правки в библиотеку самостоятельно, взяв их из [pull-request](https://github.com/pymorphy2/pymorphy2/pull/161).

Там нужно исправить в двух местах единственный файл - pymorphy2/units/base.py

Лично мне это помогло убрать ошибку и библиотека pymorphy2 заработала на Python 3.11

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Вариант, если нужно поправить один раз, например, чтобы запустить локально. Но те же манипуляции придется повторять каждый раз при установке везде, где вам понадобится эта библиотека. Проще просто взять pymorphy3

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке, функция `inspect.getargspec` в Python 3.11 уже не доступна. Вместо неё можно использовать функцию `inspect.signature`.

Примерно так:

```py
import inspect

def foo(a: int, b: str, *, c: float = 1.0) -> bool:
    pass

sig = inspect.signature(foo)
print(sig)
# <Signature (a:int, b:str, *, c:float=1.0) -> bool>
```

Попробуйте обновить модуль `pymorphy2` и заменить использование `inspect.getargspec` на `inspect.signature`.

Полезные ссылки:

[Документация по функции inspect.signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)

[Статья на хабре "Что нового в Python 3.11"](https://habr.com/ru/company/pythonru/blog/535116/)